# ruby-2.2.1 error during installing bundle gems Symbol not found: _i2d_ECPKParameters on PowerPC

Tags: ruby, openssl, powerpc

I successfully configured & compiled ruby-2.2.1 on my Mac mini G4 (PowerPC) Leopard 10.5.8 but during the install after all binaries and the like have been installed I get this error (shortened) How to fix it? Thanks.

```
installing binary commands:   /usr/local/bin
installing base libraries:    /usr/local/lib
....
installing default gems:      /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)
                          bigdecimal 1.2.6
                          io-console 0.4.3
                          json 1.8.1
                          psych 2.0.8
                          rake 10.4.2
                          rdoc 4.2.0
installing bundle gems:       /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0 (build_info, cache, doc, extensions, gems, specifications)

/Users/macmini/Downloads/ruby-2.2.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext
/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': dlopen(/Users/macmini/Downloads
/ruby-2.2.1/.ext/powerpc-darwin9.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Symbol not 
found: _i2d_ECPKParameters (LoadError)

Referenced from: /Users/macmini/Downloads/ruby-2.2.1/.ext/powerpc-darwin9.0/openssl.bundle

  Expected in: dynamic lookup
 - /Users/macmini/Downloads/ruby-2.2.1/.ext/powerpc-darwin9.0    /openssl.bundle
    from /Users/macmini/Downloads/ruby-2.2.1/lib/rubygems/core_ext
/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/macmini/Downloads/ruby-2.2.1/.ext/common
/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
....
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:722:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:721:in `each'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:721:in `block in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `call'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:757:in `block in <main>'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `each'
from ./tool/rbinstall.rb:754:in `<main>'
make: *** [do-install-all] Error 1
```

Comment: Many folks install Homebrew or MacPorts to manage older Macs. `i2d_ECPKParameters` is available in OpenSSL 1.0.2 or higher. I'm guessing Ruby is linking to the down level version of OpenSSL provided by Apple.

Comment: That's good to know. I've checked the version of OpenSSL and it's 1.0.1t, that might be the problem. I'll upgrade it to 1.0.2 and try again. Thanks.

Comment: As for the Homebrew of MacPorts, well it or its PowerPC port TigerBrew fails at the compilation because ruby-2+ causes _fgetattrlist undefined symbol error on PowerPC and it's got a patch at ruby-lang.org but brew doesn't apply that patch; eventually I have to do the compilation manually, but that's fine with me.

Comment: I don't know about TigerBrew or Ruby because I don't use them. But I have a PowerMac for testing software under PowerPC, and MacPorts works as expected.

Comment: AFAIK Macports justs downloads the tarball and only manages the configure part i.e. manages the dependencies but cannot do anything against the errors encountered at the make and install steps. Btw, I ve installed OpenSSL-1.0.2j and tried again but the same **i2d_ECPKParameters** error came up again. I guess there's something wrong in my OpenSSL setup.